# Google maps click event fired when onclick returns false

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm using Redfin's fast marker overlay for api v3.

Taking their clickable example available here,

https://code.google.com/p/multimarker/source/browse/trunk/fast-marker-overlay/maps-v3/example/clickable.html?r=22

I add a click listener to the initialize() function like so,

```
function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = window.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
      alert('map click'); 
  });
}
```

And modifying the marker template by adding return false after the addInfoWindow call,

```
var marker = new com.redfin.FastMarker(/*id*/i, latlng, ["<div class='marker' onclick='addInfoWindow(", i,"); return false;'>&nbsp;</div>"], null);
```

If I run this in chrome it works as expected.  addInfoWindow is called, the infowindow pops up, return false is hit and nothing else happens.  However in firefox and IE the return false seems to be ignored and the maps click event is fired alerting 'map click'.

In my real world application the maps click event fires an infowindow close event.  So in chrome the infowindow is displayed, you click the map and it closes.  In firefox/IE you click the marker, the infowindow is constructed but map click is fired and it is closed immediately.

Can anybody see the problem?  Is chrome skipping a bug firefox and IE don't like.

Comment: The return false is for preventing a reload on your page. Do you really need the map click handler as you have in your code? Does removing it makes your application work correct?

Comment: onclick on a div won't cause a reload.  On an anchor it would.  Yes I need the click handler as if the user clicks the map the infowindow should be closed.  It was the default behavour in v2.

Comment: I'm thinking it has something to do with the event propagating down to the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to the start of the onclick-attribute:

```
try{event.stopPropagation();}catch(e){event.cancelBubble=true;}
```

Comment: Nice one thank you.  I figured it was event propagation I just couldn't get it to stop propagating correctly.